# How to select and update row, so that the same row could not be selected again by any user?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am sending sms to mobile numbers using many apis at the same time, now I want to ensure that only one sms should be sent to one mobile number.

I am selecting a row using the following query

```
SELECT s_contact_name, s_contact_number, i_sms_sent_count 
FROM contacts 
WHERE i_sms_sent_count = 0 
ORDER BY ts_time_collected DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

while selecting the row I want to set field i_sms_sent_count to 1 so that this row could not be selected again by any user.

Comment: 1) Start a transaction; 2) Select the row and lock it; 3) Update the row; 4) Commit the transaction. -- As you see, only one thread will be able to lock the row in step #2

Comment: Use `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` - it will lock the row. Then update this row immediately.

Comment: @TheImpaler can you provide me the complete query? are you thinking something different that is answered by andy abi haidar?

Comment: What you do with the selected data and why do you want to restrict it ? i can imagine user can provide another where clause (lets say with `s_contact_name`) to get the same record. Please specify the use case.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I am sending sms to mobile numbers using many apis at the same time, now I want to ensure that only one sms should be sent to one mobile number.

Comment: If what you want is an UPDATE, don't use a SELECT. Otherwise, please clarify your question.

Comment: @Strawberry I want both SELECT and UPDATE at the same time(at once), please read my question again.

Comment: But you don't (appear to) do anything with the SELECT.

Comment: @Strawberry I am not sure where and how to put the UPDATE statement, to ensure this row could not be selected again by any user, please answer to my question it you have time. regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to do the `update` and then get the values.  Assuming you have a `contact_id` column:

```
update contacts 
    set i_sms_sent_count = 1,
        contact_id = (@contact_id := contact_id)  -- does nothing except set the variable
    where i_sms_sent_count = 0 
    order by ts_time_collected desc 
    limit 1;
```

Then get the information:

```
select *
from contacts c
where contact_id = @contact_id;
```

EDIT:

An alternative is:

```
start transaction;

select contact_id into @contact_id
from contacts 
where i_sms_sent_count = 0 
order by ts_time_collected desc 
limit 1
for update;

update contacts
    set i_sms_sent_count = 0
    where contact_id = @contact_id;

commit transaction;
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff for your time, it works but with a warning, how to remove this warning `Warning: #1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.`